# Does DCS intefere with SDR reception?

Tags: software-defined-radio, tone-squelch

Does digital coded squelch (DCS) interfere with the analog-to-digital conversion in software-defined radios (SDRs)?

I noticed that I can receive normal transmissions with my SDR just fine, but I have trouble demodulating DCS-encoded ones; I have to set the IF to 2+ kHz for some reason (in [CubicSDR](http://cubicsdr.com/)) in order to make the audio somewhat intelligible. Why would this be?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No. The whole point of SDR is that the physical receiver doesn't *care* what the kind of signal is it's receiving as long is bandwidth-wise narrow enough and amplitude-wise not overdriving.

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking if it interferes with demodulation?

Comment: then you'd get the same answer. But also, you specifically asked about the analog-to-digital conversion.

Comment: General recommendation: Don't try to ask "proxy questions", where you try to abstract your problem away. If you have a problem with reception in CubicSDR, why don't you ask a new question describing exactly what you're doing to transmit, and what to receive, and describes exactly the problem. Abstracting problems is great, but only as soon as you can tell yourself what's relevant!